# Hyper-V multiple virtual processors don't show up in virtual machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8.1

I'm running Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 x64.  I've created a Windows 8.1 x64 Gen2 virtual machine using all the default settings, except that I changed the "Number of virtual processors" from 1 to 2.  When I boot up the VM, the VM only shows one processor.  What am I missing?

Comment: What information are you looking at? Task Manager? By default Windows 8 shows a unified CPU % graph, not one per CPU, so that could be mistaken for only 1 vCPU. You should see a "Virtual processors" count on the same screen that lists actual # of virtual processors

Comment: I was looking at Task Manager and you are right, I see 2 virtual processors and 1 socket.  What does this mean from Windows' perspective?  Does think it has 2 cores to distribute load or just one doubly-powerful core?

Comment: Yes, it sees it as two independent processors / cores. It's working as you specified (2 virtual processors). If you want the graph to change, right click on the graph and choose "Change Graph To -> Logical Processors" and you'll see each virtual CPU usage separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run msconfig.exe
2. Go to Boot tab
3. Click on Advanced Options
4. Verify "Number of Processors" is either unchecked or checked with the correct processor count

[image]

Comment: Works!  Is this purely cosmetic or does it change the mechanics of how Windows interacts with those processors?  Is Windows now in a better position to handle multiple simultaneously running processes?

Comment: By default Windows will use all processors it can. This option is usually used to lower the number of used processes (for any reason). If you've 2 processors and define Windows to use 2 processors, nothing changes in the process scheduler regarding CPU timeslots, etc. It'd be a no-op.